# Trying to add all current AD users to a Distribution Group

Tags: powershell, csv, exchange-server

So I have been trying to add all of the current AD users to a specific distribution group.

I import the file as CSV or TXT, but I keep getting an error about not being able to transform the parameter:

So far my code has transformed, but my first attempt was

```
$update = gc 'File\path.txt' 

ForEach ($ADuser in $update) { 

Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity All -member $update  
 }
```

and my second attempt was

```
import-csv 'C:\Users\andrew.schilling\Desktop\testing.csv' 

$update = import-csv 'File\path\of\csv.csv' | select ObjectGUID


ForEach ($SamAccountName in $update) { 

$newmember = $update.ObjectGUID 

$newmember | foreach {
Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity All -Member $newmember   
 }}
```

I still get the same error:

> Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Member'. Cannot
>   convert the "System.Collections.ArrayList" value of type
>   "System.Collections.ArrayList" to type 
>   "Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.RecipientWithAdUserGroupIdParameter`1[Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.RecipientIdParameter]".

Please let me know of any suggestions!

Comment: It looks like you're adding the contents of the file to the `$update` variable, then in the loop, you're using the `$update` variable as the `-member` parameter. You might need to change this to `$ADuser`.

Comment: That seemed to do it. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this as an answer so others might see the cause and solution.

It looks like you're adding the contents of the file to the `$update` variable, then in the loop, you're using the `$update` variable as value for the `-member` parameter. This needs to be changed to `$ADuser`.

```
$update = gc 'File\path.txt' 
ForEach ($ADuser in $update) { 
    Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity All -member $ADuser  
}
```

Comment: Ya sorry I am new at this site